# Есть ли в NodeJS/Python модуль для добавления участника в группу Viber?

Tags: javascript, node.js, viber-api

Моя задача - добавлять участника в группу Viber по номеру телефона. Язык - либо Python, либо NodeJS, неважно. У меня есть список номеров телефона, по которым нужно добавлять новых участников в группу. Может быть как-нибудь можно это реализовать?

Answer (score -1):

Насчет Python точно да. У Viber есть такая вещь как Viber Python Bot:

https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/python-bot-api/

Устанавливается при помощи PIP:

```
pip install viberbot
```

Comment: ваш ответ не полон. пожалуйста, уточните явно, использованием какого метода или какого подхода можно решить задачу "меня есть список номеров телефона, по которым нужно добавлять новых участников в группу"